# Iterate through ArrayList of objects, and return the object

Tags: java, object, arraylist, return

I want to iterate through an ArrayList of objects, and then I want to return the object that has a specific attribute.

I tried this:

```
public Car findCar(String wantedColor){
    for (Car car : carList){
        if (wantedColor.equals(car.getColor())){
            return car;
        }
    }
    // Can't put return statement here because it's dependent of if statement
}
```

This doesn't work because the return statement is inside the 'if statement'. But I can't put the return statement in the indicated line, because it's dependent of the if statement...

Assume that there is always one car with each color. So there is always exactly one Car I'm looking for, no more and no less.

How can I ensure that there is always one object to be found and that it is returned?

Comment: If there should always be a match, then trowing an exception at the end of she method signalling an error would work.

Comment: Thanks for all answers! Now it's working fine, I can only accept one answer but they all help me to understand it better :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize the Car object to be returned outside the loop.

```
Car carWithWantedColor = null;
for (Car car : carList){
    if (wantedColor.equals(car.getColor())){
        carWithWantedColor =  car;
        break;
    }
}
return carWithWantedColor;
```

But if it contradicts with what you have said, and if a non-existing color is passed, this would return `null`. These kinds of things should normally be avoided IMO.

I would prefer to use [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) in this case.

If you want to terminate with an exception, you do as following

```
carList.stream()
       .filter(car -> car.getColor().equals(wantedColor))
       .findFirst()
       .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Invalid color"));
```

Comment: Excellent! Up voted... (BTW an exception can be catch)

Comment: +++ for `streams` also your list might contain a list of cars with that color, in that case use `.collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Evilguy, Yes, true. But I wanted stay with what the OP has (returns the first found object).

Answer (score 3):

> Assume that there is always one car with each color. So there is always exactly one Car I'm looking for, no more and no less.

That's an odd assumption. But if so, then what you have is fine other than you need to throw an exception at the end:

```
public Car findCar(String wantedColor){
    for (Car car : carList){
        if (wantedColor.equals(car.getColor())){
            return car;
        }
    }
    throw new RelevantException();
}
```

*([`IllegalStateException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) might be appropriate.)*

The more normal thing to do would be to **not** make the assumption that a car will be found, and have the method return `null` (documenting it, of course) when none is found:

```
public Car findCar(String wantedColor){
    for (Car car : carList){
        if (wantedColor.equals(car.getColor())){
            return car;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Excellent and well explained.